# Chart cannot get response when page loads first time in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, charts, ionic-framework, angular-chart

I have a problem when making an ionic app about the chart cannot get response when page loads first time with "Item 1" and "New York" as initial selected option like my screenshot below: [image: initial selected option]

**controller.js**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', '$state', '$filter', '$location', 'DOLLTYPE', 'REGION', function($scope, $q, $http, $timeout,  $interval, $state, $filter, $location, DOLLTYPE, REGION) {
   $http
    .get('js/data2.json')
    .then(function(region) {

        var i = region.length -1;

        for (i; i >= 0; i--) {
            REGION.add(region[i]);
        };

    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log('Error fetching region data: ', error)
    })

    $http
    .get('js/data.json')
    .then(function(result) {

        var i = result.length -1;

        for (i; i >= 0; i--) {
            DOLLTYPE.add(result[i]);
        };

    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log('Error fetching doll data: ', error)
    })

 $scope.title = "Dashboard";


 $scope.dash = [];
 $scope.datas = [];
 $scope.avg = [];
 $scope.avgy = [];
 $scope.data = [[]];
 $scope.labels = [[]];
 $scope.date = [];


 $scope.place = [];
 $scope.ayv = [];

 $scope.dolltype = [];
 DOLLTYPE
     .all()
     .then(function(dolltype){ 
         $scope.dolltype    = dolltype;
         $scope.dash2       = $scope.dolltype[0];
     });


 $scope.regiontype = [];
 REGION
     .all()
     .then(function(regiontype){ 
        $scope.regiontype = regiontype;
        $scope.dash1      = $scope.regiontype[0];
     })

 $scope.change = function(dash1) {
  $scope.place = dash1;
 }

 $scope.change2 = function(dash2) {
   $scope.doll= dash2.id;
 }


 $scope.place.name = 'Please select';

 $scope.$watchCollection('[place, doll]', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.colours = [
      { // Blue
        fillColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(47,64,200,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(67,43,177,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
      },
      { // Red
        fillColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(200,15,9,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(190,50,11,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
      },
       { // Green
        fillColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(18,177, 26,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(80,200,11,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
      }
    ];


 $http.get('js/data4.json').success(function(result) { 
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $scope.dash.msg  = result.message;
   $scope.prices = result.data;
   deferred.resolve($scope.prices);
   angular.forEach($scope.prices,function(value,index){
   var values =  {
                  value : value.value,
                  date : new Date(value.created_at.replace(/-/g,"/"))
    };

    $scope.datas.push(values.value);
    $scope.dash.price = $scope.datas[2];
    $scope.date.push($filter('date')(values.date,'dd-MMM'));    
    $scope.date.splice(2); 
    return deferred.promise;       
    })}).error(function(data, status) {


   console.error('Error', status, data);
   }); //End get price value

 $http.get('js/data5.json').success(function(result) { 
   $scope.averageprice = result.data;
   angular.forEach($scope.averageprice,function(value,index){
   var avgvalue =  {
                    average: value.average,
                    date : new Date(value.created_at.replace(/-/g,"/"))
    };
    console.log (avgvalue);
    $scope.avg.push(avgvalue.average);
    })}).error(function(data, status) {


   console.error('Error', status, data);
   }); //End get average price value

   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('js/data3.json').success(function(result) { 
   $scope.averageyearprice = result.data;
   deferred.resolve($scope.averageyearprice);
   console.log ($scope.averageyearprice);
   $scope.avgy.push($scope.averageyearprice.yearly_average);
   return deferred.promise;
   }).error(function(data, status) {


  }); //End get average year price value

  $scope.data[0] = $scope.datas;
  $scope.data[1] = $scope.avg;
  $scope.data[2] =  $scope.avgy;

  $scope.labels = $scope.date;
  console.log ($scope.data[0]);

  $scope.series = [$scope.place.name, 'All (Average)', 'All (YTD Year)']; 
  console.log ($scope.series); // Add information for the hover/touch effect

 })

}])
```

**HTML Template**

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="{{title}}">
    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-assertive"></ion-nav-bar> 
 <ion-content class="has-header"> 
      <div class="list">
          <div class="row item">
            <div class="col text-left assertive">   <select name='options' ng-model="dash2" ng-change="change2(dash2)" ng-options="DOLLtype as DOLLtype.name  for DOLLtype in dolltype">

             </select></div>
           <div class="col text-right assertive"> <select name='options' ng-model="dash1" ng-change="change(dash1)" ng-options="REGIONtype as REGIONtype.name for REGIONtype in regiontype">
             </select></div>
           </div>
           <div class="row item">
             <div class="col">Current Price</div>
             <div class="col text-right assertive">{{dash.price}} %</div>
             </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row item" id="container">
              <div class="col text-center">
                        <p>{{dash.msg}}</p>
                 <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" series='series' height="100" legend="true" colours="colours"></canvas>
               </div>
              </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I am using [angular chart plugin](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) for my app. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Please check this link for [full example code](https://github.com/rebelholic/ionic-chart-selection).

Comment: What's the error you are seeing in the console? Which js is the error coming from?

Comment: @potatopeelings I don't get any error message from console but I don't know how to figure out about the chart get response when page loads first time

Answer (score 0):

Your chart directive is tied to `data` (and `labels`...).

`data` is set inside the `$scope.$watchCollection` that watches `place` and `doll`.

These 2, in turn are changed only in `$scope.change` and `$scope.change2`

And these 2 methods are only called in your ng-change. So effectively `data` is undefined unless you change the pulldowns.

If you call the code in your `$scope.$watchCollection` manually, you should be able to resolve part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide an example code like you said above?

Comment: It's difficult to trace through the code because of all the promises. However a `$scope.change($scope.dash1);` after all the promises necessary for the chart data are resolved will trigger a chart draw. Without tracing through the promises, a simple `$timeout(function () { $scope.change($scope.dash1); }, 5000);` (assuming all the required promises resolve in 5 sec) will also trigger a chart draw.